# fopen function puts garbage on the file pathname

Tags: c, arrays, string, fopen, garbage

I am making an exercise in C.

The program receives as argument the name of a file, without extension, ("p01", or "p02" and so on.)
The program must open three files named (in case "p01" was entered) "p01_c.txt", "p01_w.txt" and "p01_p.txt".
I am keeping the file path until p01 into the String `ruta` "and just append the extension "_c.txt", "_w.txt" with `strcat()` before opening the file with `fopen(ruta, "rb")`.

Now my problems start:

1)  After `fopen()`, some garbage appears in `ruta`.

2)  I cannot cut the string putting a `\0` in the position where I want to cut the string.

I searched an answer on internet but I didn’t find any, so I am here asking for the first time.

Here’s my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if(argc<2) {
        printf("\nNo se ha introducido un fichero válido\n");
        return -1;
    } else {
        char ruta [] = "";
        strncat(ruta,argv[0],strlen(argv[0])-14);
        strcat(ruta,"knapsack\\");                    // knapsack is the folder containing th files
        strcat(ruta,argv[1]);                         //  now ruta is:  ...\knapsack\p01

        FILE * fCapacidad;
        strcat(ruta,"_c.txt");                        // ruta is: ... \knapsack\p01_c.txt
        printf("1- ruta is: %s\n",ruta);               // ruta is OK
        fCapacidad = fopen(ruta , "rb");
        if(fCapacidad == NULL){
            fputs ("\nNo se ha introducido un fichero válido de capacidad\n",stderr); exit(1);
        }

        FILE * fPesos;
        printf("2- ruta is: %s\n",ruta);                // ruta HAS GARBAGE!!!
        ruta[strlen(ruta-6)] = '\0';
        printf("3- ruta is: %s\n",ruta);               // ruta IS NOT CROPPED!!!
        strcat(ruta,"_w.txt");
        printf("4- ruta is: %s\n",ruta);             //_w.txt is appended to ruta (OK)
        fPesos = fopen(ruta, "rb");
```

the output is:

```
1- ruta is: E:\C Projects\MochilaEnC\bin\Debug\knapsack\p01_c.txt
2- ruta is: E:\C Projh>w\MochilaEnC\bin\Debug\knapsack\p01_c.txt
3- ruta is: E:\C Projh>w\MochilaEnC\bin\Debug\knapsack\p01_c.txt
4- ruta is: E:\C Projh>w\MochilaEnC\bin\Debug\knapsack\p01_c.txt_w.txt
No se ha introducido un fichero vßlido de pesos
```

Comment: In this context, Conflan, it is simplest to delete the question.  It is a perfectly OK question, but it doesn't really provide illumination to anyone else.  (I don't think it likely that someone will come along and want to know "If I allocated one byte for a string and then use 40 bytes, what happens and how do I stop it happening?")  If @user3121023 had wanted to post an answer, that would have happened by now, I think.  Alternatively, you can wait for it to be put on hold and then deleted.  The key lesson is to make sure you know where (and how) you've allocated the space you're using.

Comment: Your saying you have a runtime problem, then you did not post code that cleanly compiles.   In fact the posted code doesn't even come close to compiling, much less cleanly compile.   Please post code that cleanly compiles and shows the problem.

Answer (score 2):

`char ruta[] = "";` only allocates one char to the array. It is the same as `char ruta[1] = "";`. When concatenating to the array, the bounds of the array are exceeded.
Using `char ruta[200] = "";` will allocate 200 char to the array and initialize the array to an empty string. Up to 199 characters may be concatenated to the array. You can use any value that will accommodate your memory needs, I just used 200 as an example.

The other issue of assigning a `'\0'` to an index in the array can be accomplished with `ruta[strlen(ruta) - 6] = '\0';`. It would be a good idea to verify that `ruta` had a length of at least 6 otherwise you could get a negative index.
In the posted code, the `6` was inside the parenthesis with `ruta`. That would take the address of `ruta` and subtract 6. Then `strlen()` would start from that address and try to determine the length of the string. Any result would not be the correct length of `ruta`.